# A tedious question on probability (A-Level)

Tags: probability

In a competition, team $A$ and team $B$ enter the final stage. They will play $5$ games to compete for the championship. If a team wins $3$ games, it wins the match, and the rest of the games will not be played. The probabilities that team A wins the first, second, third, fourth and fifth games are $0.5, 0.9, 0.75, 0.35, 0.7$ respectively. What is the probability that team A wins the match?

The problem is not difficult but tedious, so that I would like to ask is there any ingenious and quick solution? The answer should be $0.7697$ (correct to $4$ decimal places)

Thank you very much for your valuable time and help.

[image: my solution]

Comment: Tedious is right.  I'd do it by backwards induction, on the various possible states.  Still tedious, but at least it is organized.

Comment: Not sure I was clear:  define  a state by the number of games won by each.  Thus $(a,b)$ means that $A$ has won $a$ games, and $B$ has won $b$.  Winning states are those with $a≥4$.  Letting $P_{(a,b)}$ denote the probability that $A$ wins given that you are in $(a,b)$, it's easy to get a backwards recursion in terms of $P_{(a+1,b)}$ and $P_{(a,b+1)}$.